# Automapper version 12 fails test on MapFrom when using ToLowerInvariant()

Tags: entity-framework-core, automapper

On Version 11 of automapper the below works fine but now that i upgraded to version 12 it fails. If i remove the ".ToLowerInvariant()" part then it passes the test.

Here is the mapping code:

```
CreateMap<UserEditProfileViewModel, ApplicationUser>(MemberList.Source)
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Email, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Email.ToLowerInvariant()))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.UserName, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Email.ToLowerInvariant()))
                .ForSourceMember(src => src.Roles, opts => opts.DoNotValidate());
```

The error message is:

> Test method TIP.Tests.TIP.Web.AutoMapperProfiles.AccountManagementProfileShould.BeValid threw exception:
> AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException:
> Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
> Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type
> For no matching constructor, add a no-arg ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters
> =======================================================================================================================
> UserEditProfileViewModel -> ApplicationUser (Source member list)
> TIP.Web.Features.AccountManagement.ViewModels.UserEditProfileViewModel -> TIP.Domain.Entities.Identity.ApplicationUser (Source member list)

> Unmapped properties:
> Email

Is it a bug or something has changed in version 12? How can i move forward?

Comment: Remove `ToLowerInvariant` and use a value transformer to do that. It's up to you where you want to apply that transformer.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I will try as you suggest. Is this a new change on version 12? Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/10.0-Upgrade-Guide.html#source-validation